# Application Always Loading in IE9 Compatibility View

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

We have an ASP.NET MVC application that just recently started forcing IE into IE9 Compatibility view when loading.  We have added the following to our Layout pages

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

But the page still forces IE to compatibility mode. The issue is that we only support IE 8 and up so when we perform our server side check, it thinks the browser is IE 7 and tells the user to upgrade their browser.

Anyone know why a given browser would completely ignore the X-UA-Compatible tag and render the page in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind.  That's embarrassing.  Maybe my stupidity will save someone else in the future.

[image]

Comment: Not stupidity! And yes you saved someone else =] Access this from the Menu bar >> Tools >> Compatibility View settings.